# Compare current row value with previous row values in loop in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, row, calculated-columns

I have a table with fields - A (ID), B (Flag). I need to add a new column - C (Result) in this table and it's value will be derived based on B (Flag) field. If flag is false then keep checking previous rows till we get flag as true and then take value of A (ID) field and populate it in C (Result) column. So C will have the last value of A with B field as True.

[`Required Table`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRjZ0.png)

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T | 1 |
| 2 | F | 1 |
| 3 | F | 1 |
| 4 | T | 4 |
| 5 | T | 5 |
| 6 | F | 5 |
| 7 | T | 7 |
| 8 | F | 7 |
| 9 | F | 7 |
| 10 | F | 7 |
| 11 | T | 11 |

Comment: What is MySQL version precisely? Also provide source table as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (does `B` is CHAR(1)?).

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS (
    SELECT A, SUM(B='T') OVER (ORDER BY A) group_no
    FROM test
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT A, MIN(A) OVER (PARTITION BY group_no) previous_T
    FROM cte1
)
UPDATE test
JOIN cte2 USING (A)
SET test.C = cte2.previous_T;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=46c1edfbc42e331f9bb39a36ea71e905

In MySQL 5.x use

```sql
UPDATE test
JOIN (
    SELECT A, 
           @tmp := CASE WHEN B='T' THEN A ELSE @tmp END C
    FROM test
    JOIN (SELECT @tmp:=0) init
    ORDER BY A
) data USING (A)
SET test.C = data.C;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3f341b98b768c2a2369b5d814453b234

Comment: Thank you @Akina. 
Could you please help in understanding the the second query, I am new to SQL.     
SELECT A, 
           tmp := CASE WHEN B='T' THEN A ELSE tmp END C
    FROM test    
I understand that this part puts the value of A in C if B is true otherwise it's null. But I am not able to understand the below part. Could you please help.    
JOIN (SELECT tmp:=0) init
    ORDER BY A

Comment: @user_mf_cloud Investigate the subquery only: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2b26b244838466dfeaa3924eb42c1dd2